# Live Updating Selenium Browser?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I have another question on Selenium. I've been learning a lot on Java over last couple weeks (still relatively new), and frequently make mistakes in my logic. So I was wondering if there is any way to change code in Eclipse and than run it on the WebBrowser without having to exit and restart? Because it would take a lot of time getting back to that point :(

Comment: What do you mean without having to exit and restart?

Comment: This is called [hot code replace](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F)

Comment: Thank you Luiggi, I didn't know this before :)